# HTML5 div styles not working

Tags: html, styles

My page (which uses HTML5) works fine with no doctype but when I add the HTML5 doctype then the styles on the `<div>`s don't seem to work (specifically, one `<div>` which is supposed to be aligned 20 pixels from the left isn't aligning... another `<div>` which is supposed to have a height of 90% reverts to the default height... and another `<div>` which I've changed the line spacing and character spacing seems to use the default line spacing and character spacing).  Styles on the `<span>`s work just fine though... it only seems to be the `<div>`s that have the problem.  I've changed `<div>` to `<section>`... still doesn't work.  I've tried inline styles, then switched to a style sheet... neither way seems to work.  I threw in some `display:block;` (not sure what that does) but it didn't seem to do anything.

And by the way, nothing's wrong with the code.  I ran it through a validator and it's got no errors at all.

Comment: If at all possible, please go to http://jsfiddle.net and create a self-contained example that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Here's my page with the stuff dummied out:
[link](http://kulukuku.webs.com/problem.htm).
Here is the exact same thing, with the doctype removed: [link](http://kulukuku.webs.com/problem2.htm).
You will see it looks different... some parts are aligned differently (more the way I want them) and when you click the button then the text will all be visible on the page on the one with no doctype (unlike the one with the HTML5 doctype, where it only shows a few lines and adds a scrollbar... which is not what I want).

Comment: i've made you one for people to help you - http://jsfiddle.net/Px4wh/

Comment: Thanks... I wasn't sure how to use jsfiddle.net so I didn't bother.  There is a problem though... on the jsfiddle.net version the button isn't working for some reason.  Just pointing out that it's not my code, as it works in the links that I gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your CSS

```
.indented {
    display: block;
    left: 20;
    position: relative;
}
```

Should be:

```
.indented {
    display: block;
    left: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Note that you must specify a unit value for the value of `20` - otherwise it may be ignored (which is what is causing your problem!)